# Java: Highlighting all derived data members

Tags: java, eclipse, inheritance, intellij-idea

Is there any editor for Java that is capable of highlighting **all** inherited members? It seems to be a very useful feature to aid in understanding the structure of the derived class that accesses members of the base class(es). I'm personally using `Intellij-IDEA` and if you are aware of any way to that there, please do share. All other editors are welcome!

For example you can sometimes see the following scenario (and please do not consider this example serious).

```
class A {
    ...
    protected int a;
    protected int x;
    ...
}

class B extends A {
    ...
    protected int b;
    void isntThatCoolIfSomeoneOverridesA() {
        a = b;
        x = b * b;
    }
    ...
}
```

UPDATE: extended the example

The usage of `a` and `x` in class `B` needs to be highlighted, because both are **the inherited data members** of class `A`.

Comment: Are A and B defined in the same source file?

Comment: A and B is just an example, they may not be in the same file and the hierarchy may be more complex (i.e. A => B => C) It is useful in my scenario to highlight usages of *all derived data members* at once. Highlighting just one data member is not enough. In ABC example I may want to highlight the usages of data members of A and B in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question; no I don't know of any IDE that highlights fields in that way.

I can kind of see the reason you would like it. If you are using IntelliJ and on the field you hold down the Ctrl key and hover over the field it tells you where it is defined.

I know this is a bit off topic but if the reason you want this syntax highlighting for inherited methods could it be that the codebase you are working on uses to much inheritance and not not enough composition?

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that I've been looking at how inherited protected variables are used directly in derived classes few times, and it is much easier to understand the logic if they are all highlighted at once. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Eclipse:**

It is possible to highlight invocations of inherited methods, but not for fields.
You may turn this on in Preferences dialog, under Java -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring.
In elements list view, choose Java -> Inherited method invocations, check Enable and edit how it should be highlighted.

Comment: I've opened a feature request: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=348368

Answer (score 1):

**NetBeans:** Right-click -> Navigate -> Inspect hieararchy
     You can also switch the logic - top-down or bottom-up

Non-editor options:

- **JavaDoc** - see the TREE link
- Also check **JBoss Tattletale**.

Answer (score 1):

**IntelliJ:**

If the classes are defined in the same source file, the normal variable highlighting does this. You can highlight on demand using `Search` -> `Highlight Usages in File`. Alternatively, enable `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Highlight usages of element at caret`) to always highlight the element in which the editor caret is placed.

`Search` -> `Find Usages` is often more useful, as it searches a scope (typically the project sources) for usages of a variable, field, member, class ...

Comment: The question is to highlight **all** derived data members.

Comment: As you can only have one active editor window at a time, how would highlighting be done? The mentioned method is the only way I know in IntelliJ to highlight things. If by highlighting you mean syntax coloring, IntelliJ does that out of the box. If you want an overview of all the things in your class, you have the Structure tool window.

Comment: I would want to highlight all derived data members in a single file. As I realize there may not yet be such usage/highlighting tool, it seems to me that it may be useful!

Comment: I still don't get what you mean by highlighting. IntelliJ displays all member variables (including inherited ones) in a different color than all other variables. If you want them to have a distinct background, just define it in the Preferences: Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> Java -> Instance Fields.

Comment: I want to highlight **only the inherited data members**. They are not distinctly highlighted to data members of the derived class in Intellij.

Comment: Ah, that is new. I think the only way to do this is using an inspection. One way is to create a Structural Search inspection, but I only have CE here, and it does not support that. Alternatively, if structural search doesn't cut it, you can write your own plugin to add the inspection. That should not be too dificult: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-own-inspections.html

Answer (score 0):

Why need to hightlight? Because we can read the code more easily.  Hightlight is one way,but not best. As you can not force everyone to use that editor even it is exist.  The other ways is to using this & super in the code itself to differaciate them when you write code. Java is so flexible, but we can make our own rule, or company's own rule to let others read code more easily.  When i debug code like a.b(f.c(),e.k()) , I really hate it to step in and out or use watch to check the value...